# Count number of entries made by id in a table in Yii2?

Tags: mysql, yii2

[image]

I have a table like this now what i want to  do is count the records for each ID where STATUS is COMPLETED
.
Something like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE ID= foreach(ID)
AND STATUS=1

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, count(id) as count from table where status='COMPLETED' group by id;
```

Basically you need to use group by clause in MySQL.

Comment: Yes i used the same thing Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Active Record as this:

I assuming you have you table model named like `Job`, then you can get a needed value as this:

```
$number = Job::find()->where(['STATUS' => 'Completed'])->count();
```

or it is always better to store `constant` properties in the model like this:

```
class Job extends ActiveRecord {
         const STATUS_COMPLETED = 'Completed';
```

then your ActiveQuery will look like this:

```
$number = Job::find()->where(['STATUS' => Job::STATUS_COMPLETED])->count();
```

Also here is the full description: [Querying Data](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#querying-data)

Comment: I did it using SELECT created_by as id, COUNT(*) as pcount
        FROM `cards`
        WHERE print_status=1
        GROUP BY created_by
        "

Answer (score -1):

```php
$any_var = Your_Table::find()->where(['status' => 'Cimpleted'])->select('id')->orderBy('id')->groupBy('id')->count ();
```